# How to create an XML text node with an empty string value (in Java)

Tags: java, xml

I am using a `Transform` object to save my XML file but it seems to drop empty text nodes.  Is there any way to create (and keep) a text node with an empty string i.e. "".

Here is how I create the node:

```
Element type = doc.createElement("TYPE");

type.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
```

It is just that sometimes `value` is an empty string "".  When I look at the XML with a text editor I see

```
<TYPE />
```

instead of

```
<TYPE></TYPE>
```

After I read this XML file back in and traverse the nodes the <TYPE> element simply doesn't have any children even though I explicitly created one #text node for it!

EDIT - Happy Thanksgiving (for my fellow Canadians)

Important note, I am not working from a known set of tags, rather the program I am working on uses the presence of a text node to assign a `JTextField` to the GUI.  It is just that sometimes the field is left empty (not null but "").  When I store that field and then read it back the GUI doesn't render the `JTextField` anymore because there is no text node.  So I am looking at ways to create an XML document that creates a text node even if there is nothing in it.  If that simply can't be done with XML then I will have to use an attribute to mark tags that are editable (somewhat like Andrey Breslav suggested) and so should have a `JTextField` assigned.

I will try Mads Hansen's suggestion of a non-breaking space.

Comment: <TYPE></TYPE> is equivalent to <TYPE />

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A text node *without text* ***is not a text node***.

If you are trying to control how the XML element is serialized, `<TYPE/>` and `<TYPE></TYPE>` are equivalent, and it will not matter to an XML processor if either was used.  Both are declaring a TYPE element without any `text()`. Most processors will serialize an empty element as a self-closing element.

**If you really want to prevent the element from being serialized as self-closing, you could get cute and add a zero-width space as the text node value:** `<TYPE>&#x200B;</TYPE>` which will look like: `<TYPE></TYPE>`.

It isn't technically an "empty" string, but might achieve what you want, and will not pad with space if the text node is selected and used.

Comment: This does exactly what I want.  I had to change my focus listener to replace empty strings with &#x200B; but that was somewhat trivial.  The only major drawback is that if someone was manually editing the XML file and forgot to put a non-breaking space in an empty field it messes up my GUI - but I can live with that :)

Answer (score 5):

From an XML point of view, there is no difference between `<TYPE/>` and `<TYPE></TYPE>`. There are both equivalent and can be used interchangeably. For an XML parser it means, that there is no text. The parser doesn't distinguish between "no text" and a "zero length text".

In contrast Java's `null` and `""` are totally different concepts.

So if you want to map from Java values to XML and vice versa you have to handle that mismatch. And there are several possible alternatives. For example you can abandon `null` values for your String variables. Then you have to ensure, that all your String variables are initialized with empty strings. Or you can say a TYPE element without a text child (serialized as `<TYPE/>` or `<TYPE></TYPE>`) means the empty string in Java and a missing TYPE element stands for `null`. It's your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for what you are looking for:

```
try{
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder=docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    //root Elements -- Response
    Document doc=docBuilder.newDocument();
    doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
    Element response=doc.createElement("Data");
    doc.appendChild(response);

    // Child Element -- Play
    Element hangup=doc.createElement("Type");
    response.appendChild(hangup);

    //Writer the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer=transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");

    DOMSource source=new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result=new StreamResult(sayOut);
    //StreamResult result=new StreamResult(System.out);

    transformer.transform(source,result);
    logger.info("===========XML GENERATION DON FOR HANGUP============");

}catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
    logger.error(" ==============2======== ERROR IN PRASERCONFIGURATION ===================================");
    pce.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output Generated By It:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
<Type/>
</Data>
```

Hope I have given right thing... although I agree with that `<Type/>` or `<Type></Type>` has no difference with respect to XML Parser.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a string attribute instead of tag contents. Another option is to use contents but put an attribute in case the contents is empty string.

Comment: I tried this and it does work but made the XML file about 20% larger and just didn't look right IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the XML [specs](http://www.xml.com/axml/target.html#charsets), an empty string '' is not really defined amongst the set of **valid** characters. so it is possible that the document builder simply ignores any occurrence of characters which are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue where when the XML was parsed back in, `<Element />` was treated as null when what I needed was `<Element></Element>` so it would be parsed in as an empty string. I ended up working around this by adding an empty comment node to it so it ended up looking like this `<Element><!----></Element>`.

Sorry if this doesn't directly answer the question but this is top answer on google so thought someone might find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should anotate your field with

```
@XmlElement(nillable=true)
```

Just set it to null and you will get:

```
<TYPE xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

It indicates that an element is empty.

Otherwise, if you want just open and close tags, just set its value to "" (empty String). And you will get:

```
<TYPE></TYPE>
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work, and OP said explicitly in the question, *"sometimes value is an empty string "". When I look at the XML with a text editor I see `<TYPE />` instead of `<TYPE></TYPE>`."*