# Difference between .string and .text BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I noticed something odd about when working with BeautifulSoup and couldn't find any documentation to support this so I wanted to ask over here.

Say we have a tags like these that we have parsed with BS:

```
<td>Some Table Data</td>
<td></td>
```

The [official documented](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) way to extract the data is `soup.string`. However this extracted a NoneType for the second `<td>` tag. So I tried `soup.text` (because why not?) and it extracted an empty string exactly as I wanted.

However I couldn't find any reference to this in the documentation and am worried that something is a miss. Can anyone let me know if this is acceptable to use or will it cause problems later?

BTW I am scraping table data from a web page and mean to create CSVs from the data so I do actually need empty strings rather than NoneTypes.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`.string` on a `Tag` type object returns a `NavigableString` type object. On the other hand, `.text` gets all the child strings and return concatenated using the given separator. Return type of .text is `unicode` object.

From the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring), A `NavigableString` is just like a Python `Unicode` string, except that it also supports some of the features described in [Navigating the tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree) and [Searching the tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree).

From the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) on `.string`, we can see that, If the html is like this,

```
<td>Some Table Data</td>
<td></td>
```

Then, `.string` on the second td will return `None`.
But `.text` will return an empty string, which is a `unicode` type object.

For greater convenience,

`string`

- Convenience property of a `tag` to get the single string within this tag.
- If the `tag` has a single string child then the return value is that string.
- If the `tag` has no children or more than one child then the return value is `None`
- If this `tag` has one child tag then the return value is the 'string' attribute of the child tag, recursively.

And `text`

- Get all the child strings and return concatenated using the given separator.

If the `html` is like this:

```
<td>some text</td>
<td></td>
<td><p>more text</p></td>
<td>even <p>more text</p></td>
```

`.string` on the four `td` will return,

```
some text
None
more text
None
```

`.text` will give result like this,

```
some text

more text
even more text
```

Comment: I wonder why `.text` is not mentioned in the documentation...

Comment: @S.B it is mentioned as get_text() method in doc.
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 7):

If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None:

example:

```
<td>sometext<p>sometext</p></td>
```

The above code will return NoneType if: td.string is done because the td contains texts as well as another p tag. But td.text will give : sometextsometext

Answer (score 0):

The element

```
<td></td>
```

does *not* contain an empty string. It is equivalent to

```
<td/>
```

which has no child. For XML, "no text" and "zero length text" is the same.

So `soup.string` is correct to return `NoneType`.

See also [How to create an XML text node with an empty string value (in Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884876/how-to-create-an-xml-text-node-with-an-empty-string-value-in-java)

Comment: So in other words the `.string` reflects the html in that there is no string in the empty tag. Whereas the `.text` reflects what is actually seen as in an empty string? Apologies if that is overly simplified.