# Beautiful Soup returns element wrapped in <div> tags. How do I strip them?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse information from this web page: http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/quickchart.asp?symb=AAPL

The python code

```
list = [td.find('div') for td in soup1.find_all('td')]
```

returns 20 items.  For example

```
print list[10]
```

returns

```
<div>100.60</div>
```

How do I simply have beautiful soup return "100.60".  Alternatively, how could I strip the tags?

Comment: print list[10].text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `text` inside the tag using `.text` or `.string` method. In your case both will work. `.text` will return a `unicode` string and `.string` will return a `NavigableString` object.

```
print list[10].text
```

or,

```
print list[10].string
```

Check also the [difference between `.text` and `.string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25328374/1113211).

Also you can strip them using `strip` method for `string` objects. like,

```
list[10].text.strip()
```

Comment: Thank you!  I feel like an idiot.  I'd always (ignorantly) assumed .text/.string was used to pull text placed outside of tags.