# Crawling sitemap.xml via python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am crawling a sitemap.xml and my objective is to find all the url's and the incremental count of them.

Below is the structure of the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.htcysnc.com/m/designer-sarees</loc>
        <lastmod>2014-09-01</lastmod>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.htcysnc.com/m/anarkali-suits</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-09-01</lastmod>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
```

Below is my code

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import gzip
from StringIO import StringIO


def crawler():
    count=0
    url="http://www.htcysnc.com/sitemap/sitemap_product.xml.gz"
    old_xml=requests.get(url)
    new_xml=gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(old_xml.content)).read()
    #new_xml=old_xml.text
    final_xml=BeautifulSoup(new_xml)
    item_to_be_found=final_xml.findAll('loc')
    for i in item_to_be_found:
        count=count+1
        print i
        print count
    crawler()
```

My output is like this

```
<loc>http://www.htcysnc.com/elegant-yellow-green-suit-seven-east-p63703</loc>
1
<loc>http://www.htcysnc.com/elegant-orange-pink-printed-suit-seven-east-p63705</loc>
2
```

Need the output as links without loc and /loc. Have tried replace command but that is throwing an error.

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: Sorry, the post got messed up. Have edited it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here every item in `item_to_be_found` list is a `Tag` type object so you can get the string inside `<loc>` tag using `.text` or `.string` on them. Though `.text` and `.string` have [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327693/difference-between-string-and-text-beautifulsoup/25328374#25328374) both will work same in this case.

```
for loc in item_to_be_found:
    print item_to_be_found.index(loc) + 1, loc.text
```

this will give you a result like

```
1 http://www.htcysnc.com/m/designer-sarees
2 http://www.htcysnc.com/m/anarkali-suits
```

Comment: why do i keep getting loc undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop, you can use some attributes instead that may make your code a little faster.

```
print i.text.strip()
```

That should give you the necessary information without any tags.