# Can't find string after a tag with BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In this HTML I want to get the string of it but no matter what I try it doesn't work (string = none)

```
      <a href="/analyze/default/index/49398962/1/34925733" target="_blank">
       <img alt="" class="ajax-tooltip shadow radius lazy" data-id="acctInfo:34925733_1" data-original="/upload/profileIconId/default.jpg" src="/images/common/transbg.png"/>
       Jue VioIe Grace
      </a>
```

There's a few of these on the page and I tried this:

```
print([a.string for a in soup.findAll('td', class_='tou')])
```

The output is just none.

EDIT: here is the entire page HTML, hope this helps, just to clarify, I need to find all instances like the one above and extract their string

http://pastebin.com/4mvcMsJu

Comment: Which "string" did you want as the output? `Jue VioIe Grace`? Something else?

Comment: Yeah but whenever I do the the output is 'None'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the *a* from the parent *td* and call *.text*, the text is inside the anchor which is a child of the td:

```
print([td.a.text for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='tou')])
```

There obviously is a td with the class tou or you would not be getting a list with None:

```
In [10]: html = """<td class='tou'>
          <a href="/analyze/default/index/49398962/1/34925733" target="_blank">
       <img alt="" class="ajax-tooltip shadow radius lazy" data-id="acctInfo:34925733_1" data-original="/upload/profileIconId/default.jpg" src="/images/common/transbg.png"/>
       Jue VioIe Grace
      </a>
      </td>"""

In [11]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

In [12]: [a.string for a in soup.find_all('td', class_='tou')]
Out[12]: [None]

In [13]: [td.a.text for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='tou')]
Out[13]: [u'\n\n       Jue VioIe Grace\n      ']
```

You could also call .text on the td:

```
In [14]: [td.text for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='tou')]
Out[14]: [u'\n\n\n       Jue VioIe Grace\n      \n']
```

But that would maybe get more than you want.

using your full html from pastebin:

```
In [18]: import requests

In [19]: soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://pastebin.com/raw/4mvcMsJu").content,"html.parser")

In [20]: [td.a.text.strip() for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='tou')]
Out[20]: 
 [u'KElTHMCBRlEF',
 u'game 5 loser',
 u'Cris',
 u'interestingstare',
 u'ApoIlo Price',
 u'Zary',
 u'Adrian Ma',
 u'Liquid Inori',
 u'focus plz',
 u'Shiphtur',
 u'Cody Sun',
 u'ApoIIo Price',
 u'Pobelter',
 u'Jue VioIe Grace',
 u'Valkrin',
 u'Piggy Kitten',
 u'1 and 17',
 u'BLOCK IT',
 u'JiaQQ1035716423',
 u'Twitchtv Flaresz']
```

In this case `td.text.strip()` gives you the same output:

```
In [23]: [td.text.strip() for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='tou')]
Out[23]: 
[u'KElTHMCBRlEF',
 u'game 5 loser',
 u'Cris',
 u'interestingstare',
 u'ApoIlo Price',
 u'Zary',
 u'Adrian Ma',
 u'Liquid Inori',
 u'focus plz',
 u'Shiphtur',
 u'Cody Sun',
 u'ApoIIo Price',
 u'Pobelter',
 u'Jue VioIe Grace',
 u'Valkrin',
 u'Piggy Kitten',
 u'1 and 17',
 u'BLOCK IT',
 u'JiaQQ1035716423',
 u'Twitchtv Flaresz']
```

But you should understand that there is a difference. Also the difference between [.string vs .text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327693/difference-between-string-and-text-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @John1024,  read the question, *The output is just none.* If `soup.find_all('td', class_='tou')` found nothing then there would be no None there as the loop would never happen.

Comment: The OP wrote `none` and not `None`.  There is more than a little  ambiguity in the question.   We will have to wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @John1024, the html just did

Comment: No worries, I added a link to an answer that explains .string vs .text, it should hopefully  make the difference clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open('input.html'), 'lxml')
>>> [tag.text.strip() for tag in soup]
[u'Jue VioIe Grace']
```

If we want to restrict the search to text in *anchor* tags:

```
>>> [tag.text.strip() for tag in soup.findAll('a')]
[u'Jue VioIe Grace']
```

Note that there are no `td` tags in your sample input and no tag has the attribute `class_='tou'`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your `soup` variable is made off that html piece of code then the output you get is `None` because there is no `td` element inside it, and of course there is not `td` element with `class=tou`.

Now, if you want to get that text maybe you could call `soup.findAll(text=True)` which outputs something like `['\n', '\n       Jue VioIe Grace\n      ']`