# Web scraping - Get text from a class with BeautifulSoup and Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the text ("Showing 650 results") from a website.

The result of I am looking for is:

```
 Result : Showing 650 results
```

The following is the Html code:

```
<div class="jobs-search-results__count-sort pt3">
            <div class="jobs-search-results__count-string results-count-string Sans-15px-black-55% pb0 pl5 pr4">
                Showing 650 results
            </div>
```

Python code:

```
    response = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    text = {}
    link = "jobs-search-results__count-string results-count-string Sans-15px-black-55% pb0 pl5 pr4" 
    for div in soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : link}):
        text[div.text]
    text
```

So far it looks like my code is not working.

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. Why would it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You don't need `soup.find_all` if you're looking for one element only, `soup.find` works just as well
2. You can use `tag.string`/`tag.contents`/`tag.text` to access inner text

---

```
div = soup.find('div', {"class" : link})
text = div.string
```

Comment: or even `tag.text`! ps.: even though it's an old way of calling `.string`, it'll always return the same thing I guess. ([*Actually it depends*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327693/difference-between-string-and-text-beautifulsoup)) =)

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Thanks :]

Comment: I am getting the following error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @David That means the div with the class does not exist.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that is weird.  According to the html is there

Comment: @David Just tried this and I get `Showing 650 results`.

Comment: it appears to work just fine with the html code, but when loaded from the actual website I believe there is a problem with the "soup = BeautifulSoup()"
If you have time do you mind trying it from the actual url

https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=aircraft%20powerplant%20repairer&location=United%20States&locationId=us%3A0

Answer (score 0):

**Old**: `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`

*"Development on the 3.x series of Beautiful Soup ended in 2011, and the series will be discontinued on January 1, 2021, one year after the Python 2 sunsetting date."*

**New**: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

*"Beautiful Soup is a library that makes it easy to scrape information from web pages. It sits atop an HTML or XML parser, providing Pythonic idioms for iterating, searching, and modifying the parse tree."*