# Beautiful scrape not grabbing column data due to href in < td

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup web scrape will not correctly scrape the data from a given column of a table.

It works to get (scrape) all the data in the table EXCEPT for the data in the 'Player' column; the output shows all the player names as 'none'.

[Output Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhXur.png)

The only difference in the td element for the data in the 'player' column vs. all other td elements in the tr is that there is a href before the 'td' in the player data element, as displayed in the images below.

[inspect  in each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvbPz.png)

[td in the 'Player' column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HGVS.png)

How would i go about changing my code to get the players names? Is it the href in the  for the 'Player' data that is screwing my script?   If so, how do i account for this?

```js
#HOME_SKATERS
#FIRST_TWO_GAMES

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
table = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (400959564,400959565):
    url = requests.get("http://www.espn.com/nhl/boxscore?gameId={}".format(i))
    if not url.ok:
        continue
    data = url.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    #Add the game ID to the list of soups to keep track of multiple players with same game ID
    table.append((i,soup.find_all('table', {'class' : 'mod-data'})[5].find_all('tr')[2:20]))

data = []
soups = []
game_id = []
for i,t in table:
#Use .contents method to turn the soup into list of items
    soups = [j.contents for j in t]
    for s in soups:
#Use .string method to parse the values of different columns
        data.append([a.string for a in s])
#Append the Game ID
        game_id.append(i)


#Create a DataFrame from the data extracted
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['Player', 'G', 'A','Plus_Minus', 'SOG', 'MS', 'BS', 'PN', 'PIM', 'HT', 'TK', 'GV', 'SHF', 'TOT', 'PP','SH', 'EV', 'FW', 'FL', 'Faceoff_Pct']
df['Game ID'] = game_id
#df.to_csv('HOME_SKATERS.csv')
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
data.append([a.string for a in s])
```

to

```
data.append([a.text for a in s])
```

Outputs:

```
             Player  G  A Plus_Minus SOG MS BS PN PIM HT    ...     GV SHF  \
0       J. Armia RW  0  0         -2   0  0  1  0   0  1    ...      0  21   
1   D. Byfuglien D   0  1          0   5  1  1  1   2  1    ...      1  29   
2        A. Copp C   0  0         -1   1  0  1  0   0  1    ...      0  18   
3        M. Dano C   0  0         -1   0  0  0  0   0  0    ...      0  14   
4      N. Ehlers LW  0  0         -1   2  1  0  0   0  0    ...      0  20   
5     T. Enstrom D   0  0         -2   1  1  2  0   0  1    ...      0  23   
6     D. Kulikov D   0  0          1   0  0  0  0   0  1    ...      0  20   
7       P. Laine RW  0  1          2   2  1  0  0   0  0    ...      1  23   
8      B. Little C   0  1          0   3  2  0  0   0  0    ...      0  22   
9       A. Lowry LW  0  0          0   4  1  0  0   0  3    ...      1  27   
10   S. Matthias C   0  0         -1   2  0  0  0   0  2    ...      2  23   
11  J. Morrissey D   0  0         -2   2  0  2  1   2  0    ...      0  20   
12      T. Myers D   0  0          0   2  1  2  1   2  2    ...      1  27   
13  M. Perreault C   1  0         -1   2  0  0  0   0  1    ...      0  23   
14  M. Scheifele C   1  0         -1   4  0  0  0   0  0    ...      0  23   
15      B. Tanev LW  0  0         -1   0  0  0  0   0  1    ...      0  15   
16     J. Trouba D   0  0         -4   5  0  4  1   2  4    ...      1  30   
17    B. Wheeler RW  0  0         -1   2  2  1  0   0  0    ...      0  23
```

see [Difference between .string and .text BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327693/difference-between-string-and-text-beautifulsoup)

An example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = '<td style="text-align:left;"><a href="http://www.espn.com/nhl/player/_/id/3961/blake-wheeler">B. Wheeler</a> RW</td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
td = soup.find("td")
print (td.string)
print (td.text)
```

Outputs:

```
None
B. Wheeler RW
```

Because you have "markup" in the "td" element.