# Python - strip numbers from file and sum them up

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, numbers

### I recently started to learn python. Now i want to strip numbers from a website to sum them up.

**Here is my code:**

```
# read data -> extract numbers -> compute sum
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html')
file = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = file('span')
calcs = 0
for tag in tags:
    tag.decode()
    calcs += int(tag.string)
print(calcs)
```

In line 11 (calcs += ...) i wasn't sure what to do and somewhere in the internet i found .string, which helped me get the numbers out of the lines, but i'm not really sure why this works or what .string does. Couldn't find any source of information about that by myself. If i change .string to .int it gets 'None'

I hope anyone can explain me the use of .string.

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: string is a member variable that is used to extract data from the tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327693/difference-between-string-and-text-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.string` is a member variable of the `Tag` object.  There is no `.int` member, which is why you would get `None` when trying to access the value.

What is happening in your `calcs=...` line is that you are getting the data from the tag as a `str`, and then converting the `str` to an `int`, which seems to be a completely valid way of getting your list of numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the `tag.string` to `int`

```
tags = file('span')
calcs = sum([int(tag.string)  for tag in tags])
```