# Pulling company name from webpage within <a> tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to streamline my data collection by using Python 3.7 and BeautifulSoup to pull company name, if that company is approved or other, and if they are marketing to residential and/or businesses from this CT license list:

`http://www.dpuc.state.ct.us/electric.nsf/$FormByElectricApplicantsView?OpenForm&Start=1&Count=1000&ExpandView`

If I can get any help on how to finish the code to at least create a list of appended companies names within Python that would be a big help.

I am learning as I go and able to connect to the site and pull in the source code.

So far, I know this part of the code to work but not quite sure where to go from here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get("http://www.dpuc.state.ct.us/electric.nsf/$FormByElectricApplicantsView?OpenForm&Start=1&Count=1000&ExpandView")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')
```

I can see the company name within the source code but not sure the best way to extract it and the others into a list:

```
<a href="/electric.nsf/c39dc573ab1299538525743b004d4df6/719f088ca20a6a1f85257dfd00480e13?OpenDocument">3Degrees Group, Inc.</a>
```

I would love to be able to pull all this into an csv. file at some point that has the companies, the status of the license, and who they market to but if someone can help me finish the code to put the companies in a list within Python that would much appreciated and allow me to learn by example.

Comment: If you can uniquly identify all `<a>` tags with some class you can do. `soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'xxx'}`. (Assuming multiple `<a>`in page)

Comment: Just the suppliers? Or also the aggregators?

Comment: Hi, @QHarr, just the suppliers for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**23/04/22**

`:contains()` is being deprecated and replaced with [`:-soup-contains()`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains). This was introduced with Soup Sieve 2.1.

---

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use `:contains` and `:has` to filter for only the sections pertaining to `Supplier`. You can further subset the df for columns of interest.

---

**tl;dr;**

Make the request and read response into soup object:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.dpuc.state.ct.us/electric.nsf/$FormByElectricApplicantsView?OpenForm&Start=1&Count=1000&ExpandView')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
```

Let's use some images to explain the next steps......

What we have, which may be confusing, is a lot of nested tables, but we can start by thinking of the 'top' level table of interest:

[image]

We can take from this (hover over the different `trs` in that image within the actual html and observe what is highlighted on the page to follow along. You can enter `p:nth-child(4) > table` in the browser search box to isolate this table):

[image]

True, the actual visible content is nested but we know all content of interest is within `trs` that at a given level are a series of sibling `trs`.

This bit

```
soup.select('tr:has(td:nth-of-type(1) font:contains(Supplier)) ~ tr:not(:has(td:nth-of-type(1) font:contains(Aggregator)), :has(td:nth-of-type(1) font:contains(Aggregator)) ~ tr)')
```

gathers the sibling `trs` of the 'top' level `tr` that *has* child `font` node *containing* `Supplier`, `tr:has(td:nth-of-type(1) font:contains(Supplier))`,  then removes the 'top' level `tr` *containing* `Aggregator` and its siblings. As what you have in the html is a long list of `trs`, you just want to filter out those that come after the section of interest.

Looking at the very first part (I'm using `select_one`, rather than `select`, to demonstrate the first node matched, and not the multiple siblings that are matched when we add in the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) - more about that later):

```
soup.select_one('tr:has(td:nth-of-type(1) font:contains(Supplier))')
```

Running the above gives:

[image]

Compare this to the page:

[image]

You see how we have found a way to start selecting `trs` at the top level starting with the one that (though nested) contains the `Supplier` label. However, as we know that top level is flat we need to remove everything from (and including) the `Aggregator` label. So, we add to that general sibling combinator the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class. In a nutshell we say get all `trs` that are siblings except those within the `:not`

[image]

Now we have our subset of rows of interest (green rectangle). We `for loop` over these and each time we find a node matched by `'td:nth-of-type(2) font'` we set the `status` to the value found e.g. `Approved, Pending`.....

[image]

This line:

```
if node is not None:
```

is checking whether the current `tr` contains a *'status'* child node e.g. `Approved/Pending` (which I name as `status` for output) and set the later rows identifier for this category accordingly.

If the `tr` does not have this child node then we know it is one of the other `trs` that houses the `tds` with the additional columns of info for output e.g.:

[image]

Due to the level of nesting, there are a few empty `tds` including that we don't want. These we remove using pandas later:

```
df.drop([1,2,10], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

As we want the `status` label and all the `tds` in one list, `row`, I use `extend` to extend the first list to include the second. I believe this is quicker than `insert` but would appreciate a yey/ney on that.

So, we would go, for example, from:

```
['Approved']
```

and

```
['', '', 'Yes', 'Yes', '3Degrees Group, Inc.', 'http://www.3degreesinc.com', '235 Montgomery Street, Suite 320 San Francisco, CA 94104', '(866) 476-9378', '11-11-07 12/14/2011', '']
```

to

```
['Approved', '', '', 'Yes', 'Yes', '3Degrees Group, Inc.', 'http://www.3degreesinc.com', '235 Montgomery Street, Suite 320 San Francisco, CA 94104', '(866) 476-9378', '11-11-07 12/14/2011', '']
```

These rows are added to a list called `final`. So, you have a list of lists (each row).

You can pass this list to [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to generate a dataframe ready for csv export with [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) method. You use the `columns` argument to specify the headers.

When generating the rows:

```
tds = [td.text for td in tr.select('td')]
```

We find the occasional additional whitespace and `\n` (newline) e.g.

```
['', '', '', '', 'WFM Intermediary New England Energy, LLC', '', '125 Cambridgepark Dr, Cambridge, MA 02140', '', '07-10-08  \n11/28/2007\n9/8/2011', '']
```

I implement a simple regex to remove this:

```
tds = [re.sub('\n+|\s+',' ',td.text) for td in tr.select('td')]
```

Resulting in (perhaps not best example but is illustrative):

```
['', '', '', '', 'WFM Intermediary New England Energy, LLC', '', '125 Cambridgepark Dr, Cambridge, MA 02140', '', '07-10-08 11/28/2007 9/8/2011', '']
```

**Regex:**

[image]

Finally (did you make it this far?), we want to add some headers for the dataframe. We can use the ones from the page and again, via `extend`, ensure we include our custom `status` header.

```
headers = ['Status']
headers.extend([th.text for th in soup.select('th[align]')])
```

[image]

---

Py:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, re
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://www.dpuc.state.ct.us/electric.nsf/$FormByElectricApplicantsView?OpenForm&Start=1&Count=1000&ExpandView')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
final = []
headers = ['Status']
headers.extend([th.text for th in soup.select('th[align]')])

for tr in soup.select('tr:has(td:nth-of-type(1) font:contains(Supplier)) ~ tr:not(:has(td:nth-of-type(1) font:contains(Aggregator)), :has(td:nth-of-type(1) font:contains(Aggregator)) ~ tr)'):
    node = tr.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2) font')
    if node is not None:
        status = node.text
    else:
        row = [status]
        tds = [re.sub('\n+|\s+',' ',td.text) for td in tr.select('td')]
        row.extend(tds)
        final.append(row)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(final)
df.drop([1,2,10], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.columns = headers
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Public Utilities.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

**Sample of output:**

[image]

---

**Additional reading:**

1. [Css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Nicely done! The website-html-source does not look friendly for separating the `divs` and `hrefs` by class or attributes. This is a really nice and concise solution.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you so much! This works the way I want it to. Thanks for taking the time and staring at it for some time lol. Much appreciated. Going to take this and try to learn from it and apply it to other things to crawl. Again, thank you!

Comment: And it is pretty easy to later extend for the block below.

Comment: Hey @QHarr I have been studying this for time to time throughout the day and was able to piece some of it together logically but don't understand how it is fully do the job. If you have time do you mind telling me the logic behind the code?

Comment: Absolutely will update later today. Is there any bit in particular?

Comment: @Qharr thanks so much! I got most of everything up to the `headers` part of the code. Just not sure how it is picking at the source and how the dataframe is being created and formatted. I was also curious about the `requests, re` and the `import of pandas`. I haven't seen an example online that has `pandas' being use. That just for the dataframe? Again, thanks again for taking the time to help.

Comment: Hi, I have added more info for you. Let me know,

Comment: @QHarr I really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Any other questions fire away but that's probably a fair bit for now :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
company_list = [];
for company in soup.find_all('a'):
    company_list.append(company.string);
```

You can find more details regarding this on the BeautifulSoup documentation. You likely will have to modify this code to filter out specific  tags via conditions inside the loop, but I believe that should be pretty simple.

More specifically, for your particular example, you can check the `company.get('href')` matches ".nsf" via regex or whatever you prefer.

Comment: you can do `company_list = [x.string for x in soup.find_all('a')]`. But this assumes all `<a>` tags in page are for names ( from my exp it will not be the case for most part.)

Comment: also dont use `.string` instead use `.text` better. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327693/difference-between-string-and-text-beautifulsoup

Comment: I specifically didn't use comprehension as to allow for easier conditionals, but yeah, comprehension would work for a simpler example.

Comment: This would result in a list which contains alternately the company name and its website. If OP is only looking for one or the other, he will have to split the list.

Comment: @JackFleeting Read the second part of my comment; if you pass a regex filter to match .nsf in the href tag, then it will only contain company names. (Or perhaps another conditional, I didn't read the page source in detail).