# How to determine these elements of html?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

In this answer, @Andrej Kesely use the following code to remove unnecessary elements (ads, huge space,...) from html of [this url](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for script in soup.select('script, .hcdcrt, #ad_contentslot_1, #ad_contentslot_2'):
    script.extract()

print(soup.h2.text)
print(''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.hom').contents)))
```

It seems to me that those unnecessary elements are marked by `script, .hcdcrt, #ad_contentslot_1, #ad_contentslot_2`.

Could you please elaborate how to look at the html structure (by pressing F12) to pin down them?

Comment: One way is Right Click on chrome and visualize the html DOM using https://livedom.validator.nu/ or any other online service

Comment: Thank you so much @bigbounty! I got your idea. If you don't mind, please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112871/why-does-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-contents-occur-with-only-one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bigbounty's comment solves my problem. I post it here to remove my question from unanswered list.

> One way is Right Click on chrome and visualize the html DOM using livedom.validator.nu or any other online service