# Why does error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents' occur with only one of two similar commands?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm extracting content from this [url](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'html.parser')

for script in soup.select('script, .hcdcrt, #ad_contentslot_1, #ad_contentslot_2'):
    script.extract()

entry_name = soup.h2.text
content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB cB-def dictionary biling').contents))
```

Then I got an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-e9cb11cd6b5d> in <module>
     10 
     11 entry_name = soup.h2.text
---> 12 content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB cB-def dictionary biling').contents))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

On the other hand, if I replace `cB cB-def dictionary biling` by `hom`, i.e. `content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.hom').contents))` then the code runs well. From below structure of the html, I think that `cB cB-def dictionary biling` and `hom` are very similar.

[image]

Could you please elaborate on how such problem arises and how to solve it?

Comment: What do you want to extract from the page?

Comment: @bigbounty I want to extract both content and html markup in `<div class="cB cB-def dictionary biling" ... </div>` and in `<div class="cB cB-e dcCorpEx" ... </div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'html.parser')

for script in soup.select('script, .hcdcrt, #ad_contentslot_1, #ad_contentslot_2'):
    script.extract()

entry_name = soup.h2.text
content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents))
```

When you select classes and it is `blank-spaces` in it you replace the space with `.`.

`cB`, `cB-def`, `dictionary` and `biling` is four different classes. And if you let the spaces be there the script looking for a tag with class `cB-def` inside of a tag with class `cB` and so on....

Comment: Your answer perfectly solves my problem.  Could you please suggest a tutorial for beginner to understand the commands `for script in soup.select('script, .hcdcrt, #ad_contentslot_1, #ad_contentslot_2')` and `''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents))`.