# BS4 returning AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' sometimes, how to solve this?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I wrote a piece that tries to get some data from yahoo finance. However, first attempt it failed somewhere at the start after being able to retrieve stock data (price and change in price). It gave the NoneType error. Then I ran it again, and it actually was able to retrieve suddenly that data and continued to retrieve more and failed somewhere halfway with the same error. I find it weird, since that attribute text is present in the html. Especially weird that it is able to find it in the second attempt without adjustments. Also, it is all on the same page, so it is not that I need to wait for some.
This is the error:

price = soup_ticker.find('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

This is the specific html:

`<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="32">22.12</span>`

This is my Code. Mind that im a beginner and this is all for educational purposes. I know there are probably a million ways to do things better than I have done below to achieve the same. Thank you for your help in advance and for your knowledge!

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from scraping.models import StockData

import re


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Collects a stock ticker, price, price change and date"

    # define logic of command
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # collect html
        html = urlopen('http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/A.htm')

        regex = re.compile("Display Quote & Chart for")
        regex_price = re.compile("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px)")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        # grab all postings
        td = soup.find_all("td")
        for tag in td:
            for anchor in tag.find_all('a', {'title': regex}):
                ticker = anchor.text
                html_ticker = urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + ticker + "/")
                soup_ticker = BeautifulSoup(html_ticker, 'html.parser')
                price = soup_ticker.find('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)').text
                change = soup_ticker.find('div', class_="D(ib) Mend(20px)").find_all('span')[1].text

                try:
                    # save in db
                    StockData.objects.create(
                        ticker=ticker,
                        price=price,
                        change=change,
                    )
                    print('%s added' % (ticker,))
                except:
                    print('%s already exists' % (ticker,))
            self.stdout.write('job complete')
```

Comment: you can use string instead, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use .string this [Difference between .string and .text BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327693/difference-between-string-and-text-beautifulsoup) explains the difference between .text and .string. Can't use .text in bs4 versions > 4.8.0.

Comment: Thnx for the comment, I have tried that, but ended up with the same error.
```price = soup_ticker.find('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)').string
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```
but before this error shows up, it does say this: 
Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
Does that maybe say something to you? Ill be checking stackoverflow as well to see if there are some clues regarding that replacement character.