# Extract items out of each List element and populate Dataframe with it

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This generates a result set as a `list`

```
#Dates
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500)
import requests
myURL =  "xxxxx"
page = requests.get(myURL)
#print (page)
soup = bs(page.content,"html.parser")
#print(soup.prettify)
rSet = soup.find_all("td", class_="first")
for el in rSet :
 print (el.find("first")) <-- returns "None"
 print (el) <-- returns <td class="first" rowspan="1">00:00 - 01:00</td> (for eaxmple)
```

With elements that look like this:

```
<td class="first" rowspan="1">00:00 - 01:00</td>
<td class="first" rowspan="1">01:00 - 02:00</td>
```

I Want to extract "00:00" and "01:00" (- which are Start and End Times) and populate the Dataframe in two columns. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?:

```
print(el.text)
```

Comment: It worked, is it a HTML parser? I now get `00:00 - 01:00` when i print it, do you know what the reason is?

Comment: .text it's a BeautifulSoup property and gets all the child strings.
Return a unicode object.
For more: [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327693/difference-between-string-and-text-beautifulsoup)