# How can I extract only string in this phrase? (Python BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

This is HTML source:

```
<td style="padding-right: 10px;" valign="top">1.1</td>
<td valign="top">
         If applicable, do <a href="url"> link </a> to switch one to other mode.<br/>
</td>
```

From above, how can I extract only strings?
I tried it like below.
Although first one work, second one doesn't work.

```
print(soup.find_all("td")[0].string)
print(soup.find_all("td")[1].string)
```

```
1.1
None
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the output that you would want from a working version of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.text` attribute rather then the `.string` attribute. The reason is quite complex and is explained here: [Difference between .string and .text BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327693/difference-between-string-and-text-beautifulsoup)

Here is the working version of your code:

```
import bs4
source="""
<td style="padding-right: 10px;" valign="top">1.1</td>
<td valign="top">
         If applicable, do <a href="url"> link </a> to switch one to other mode.<br/>
</td>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("td")[0].text)
print(soup.find_all("td")[1].text)
```

With output:

```
1.1

         If applicable, do  link  to switch one to other mode.
```

Feel free to use `.strip()` to remove unwanted spaces at the start and at the end.

Comment: Thx a lot! I can extract text thanks to you and I used translate() also.